# Backlight issue ASUS T300 Chi after booting

Tags: boot, brightness, login-screen, backlight

## Introduction

I am having trouble with my screen backlight after booting, so when I first enter the login screen. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 bionic. It is a fresh install, fully updated. Probably you are also interested in the video card: Intel® HD Graphics 5300 (Broadwell GT2).

## The issue

This is what happens:
When I boot my tablet/laptop, I see grub and I can select what OS I want to start (dual boot with Windows). I start Ubuntu and I see the splash screen. Then, when the login screen should show up the screen is just black. However, I can login by pressing `enter` and then just type my password and press `enter` again. Then the backlight turns on and I can use my tablet. If I then logout, the backlight stays on and the login screen is visible.

Another way to turn on the backlight is by attaching an external screen through the HDMI connecter. Then suddenly also the screen of my tablet also work. If I then disconnect the external screen, the backlight stays on.

So I think there is an issue that my backlight is turned off during booting and it needs a trigger to turn it on again.

## What I tried

I have searched for a couple of days now and found solutions like adding kernel parameters in grub, but those does not fix the issue.

I also tried with a systemd service that calls a script I made to set the backlight brightness to the maximum through the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/...` files. Without success. Then I changed the script that it writes the current brightness (with a delay) to a file in the tmp folder. When looking at this file I see that the brightness is already at it maximum.

## Additional information

Maybe this info can also help a bit: writing the value `0` to the `brightness` file in the `sys` folder will result in the same black screen. That's why I first thought the value in the `brigtness` file was `0` and I tried to force it at max through a systemd service.

---

Has anyone an idea what is the problem? Or is there another way to check (through a startup script or so that I can make myself if necessary) if the backlight is turned on or off?

## Update 1 25/08

I found that in the sys folder, there is also a file `bl_power`. So I have edited my shell script that starts through systemd a bit so I also can see what content is in `bl_power`.

I see that when it contains the value `0` the screen is on, another value turns off the backlight. Guess what, first it contains the value `0` during the boot (I guess during the splash screen), but the it changes to `4`. However, I cannot force this value to `0` through my script.

For now, this is the shell script:
    SYS="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight"
    BRIGHT="${SYS}/brightness"
    POWER="${SYS}/bl_power"
    TMP="/tmp/backlight"

```
cat /proc/uptime | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > ${TMP}
cat ${BRIGHT} >> ${TMP}
cat ${POWER} >> ${TMP}

sleep 10

cat /proc/uptime | cut -d ' ' -f 1 >> ${TMP}
cat ${BRIGHT} >> ${TMP}
cat ${POWER} >> ${TMP}

echo 0 > ${POWER}
cat ${POWER} >> ${TMP}
```

The systemd service file is as follows:
    [Unit]
    Description=Enable backlight
    After=gdm3.service

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/enablebacklight.sh
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For those who want the know the output of my script to the tmp file:

```
5.72    # uptime
937     # brightness
0       # bl_power
15.73   # uptime after 10 sec sleep
937     # brightness after 10 sec sleep
4       # bl_power after 10 sec sleep
4       # bl_power after echoing 0 to it
```

## Update 2 25/8

I have removed the `quiet` and `splash` options from the grub command line. Now the display turns off for a short time (1 second or maybe less) and then back on. Then there is a list with `[OK]` flags and then it stops. If I then press `ctrl` + `alt` + `F2` to jump to a console screen and then the same combination but with `F1`, the screen stays on and I can login through gnome. Anyone who has an idea?

I first thought the splash screen was the issue, but why can't I write `0` to `bl_power` through a systemd startup script when the login screen is shown... I tested this by creating a script that waits until `bl_power` gets a value different from `0` and then it gets into a loop that only exists when it has written the value `0` and afterwards read the value `0` from `bl_power`. As long as I do not login, the script keeps running, which means `bl_power` immediately is overwritten with a value different than `0` (I checked and it contains `4`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the 'solution' myself. If I change the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`and I uncomment the following line:

```
# WaylandEnable=false
```

Then the login screen was shown after boot (and thus the backlight was on). After one successful boot I commented out the line again, and now it still works. A bit weird, but it works now.